# Optimization with random matrix

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, random-matrices, norms

Consider $J$ a random matrix of size $n\times n$ with i.i.d. Gaussian entries $J_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/n)$. Let $f(x)=tanh(x)$, and for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x)$ denotes the vector where $f(.)$ is applied entry-wise.

My goal is to compute

$$M_n(\sigma) = \inf_{K\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{||KJf(x)||}{||Kx||}$$

In particular, how $M_n(\sigma)$ compares with $\sigma$ for $n$ large ?

Comment: with high probability $M_n(\sigma)$ is bounded by $1$; the exact probabilistic behavior of $M_n(\sigma)$ relates to the spectrum of a random matrix with dependent chi-square distributed entries; when $n$ is very large, $M_n(\sigma)$ is close to zero with high probability